# google cloud speech not returning full text

Tags: speech-recognition, speech-to-text, google-cloud-speech

I am working on google cloud speech api i tried their api with  my  flac file but they are just transcripting a some part of my flac format file.Is there anything i can do with my file to make it work perfectly.I tried testing their api on their [link](https://cloud.google.com/speech/reference/rest/v1/speech/recognize#SpeechRecognitionResult).I Pass this in the request body

{
  "audio": {
    "uri": "gs://kami1994/file-1506682082651.flac"
  },
  "config": {
    "encoding": "FLAC",
    "languageCode": "en-US",
    "sampleRateHertz": 44100,
    "maxAlternatives": 1
  }
}

But it is not returning text exactly like i spoke.

Answer (score 0):

Speech recognition engine is expected to be highly accurate but not 100%. To debug your problem further you can enable word time offsets, in recognize config.

```
"config": { "encoding": "FLAC", "languageCode": "en-US", "sampleRateHertz": 44100, "maxAlternatives": 1, **"enable_word_time_offsets": True** }
```

This would help you check if the word boundaries are detected.